# Client denied by server configuration with tomcat

Tags: regex, apache, tomcat, permissions

I have found at least a dozen entries for this error even in this forum, and many outside. All are basically saying that inside `<Directory></Directory>`, I have "deny all" directive, and no "allow" directive.

I cannot write a fixed directory to match because it is created on the fly by a backend tomcat server.

When I entered "myUrl/test/request/user1/1234567890/download", I get

> 403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /test/request/user1/1234567890/download.

httpd error log shows:

```
[error] [client xxx.xx.xx.xxx] client denied by server configuration: /data/test, referer: myUrl/test/request/user1/1234567890
```

The part beginning with "test" is created by the backend tomcat, in which "user1" and "1234567890" vary, while the other parts of the directory structure remain fixed.

In my httpd.conf, I do have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
    DocumentRoot /data
    ---
    ---
    RewriteRule ^/test - [L]
    ---
</VirtualHost>
```

How do I solve this? Even if  I create a different  and create another document root, I will need a regex. Somewhere outside , I tried this:

```
<Directory "/data/test/request/*/*/download">
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But no success.

I am using "ajp" to talk to backend tomcat and have necessary module in place and I can telnet the backend tomcat server (on 8009) . So it should not be ajp communications problem.

The "test" piece in above url is actually a "context" inside /webapps directory of tomcat. Owner in that "test" context is tomcat, but I have added read permission for everyone.

Answer (score -1):

First, I had to "deny all" for "/"

```
Directory  
    Deny from all
/Directory
```

Only then "Allow for all" for "/data"

```
Directory /data
    ---
    ---
    Allow from all
/Directory
```

Then I rearranged RewriteRule, Redirect, ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse inside the

```
VirtualHost *:80 
/VirtualHost
```

and it worked!